# Cómo multiplicar un número entero con una lista de enteros?

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, matemáticas, números-enteros

Se tiene `List<Integer> lista=new Arraylist<>();` donde lista es de tamaño n y en cada posición tiene un número entero, es decir, `lista.get(0)==2,lista.get(1)==8...,lista.get(n)==6`.

Y quisiera multiplicar un número entero, digamos **k**, por todo el número completo que forma la lista, es decir, **k** *(28...6).

Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Osea, quieres sumar todos los elementos de la lista y  luego multiplicarlos por la variable `k`?

Comment: con un ciclo? por que no has usado uno? comienza desde atrás para delante multiplicando por 10 y sumando los números de la lista, luego multiplica por k. (o concatenas todo como string y luego parseas)

Comment: @Einer no, no quiero sumar todos los elementos de la lista, quiero juntarlos, es decir, formar un solo número con todos ellos y  luego multiplicarlos por la variable k

Comment: no se podrían pasar todos los números de la lista a una sola variable entera `int n`? @ArieCwHat

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo, pero tengo una duda, si el elemento de la lista tiene 2 cifras? se concatenan o siempre está limitado a una cifra?

Comment: siempre es solo una cifra @ArieCwHat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no quiero sumar todos los elementos de la lista, quiero juntarlos, es
>   decir, formar un solo número con todos ellos

Buenos entonces tendrás que concatenar cada numero de la listay luego convertilo a `double`:

```
List<Integer> lista=new Arraylist<>();
lista.add(2);
// ..
//..

String numeroString = "";
for(int numero : lista)
{
  numeroString += String.valueOf(numero);
}

double resultadoNumeroConcatenado = Double.parseDouble(numeroString);
double resultado = k * resultadoNumeroConcatenado
```

Concatenando una lista de `n` elemento es muy probable que se sobrepase ese valor maximo de Integer, por eso utilizo `double` para evitar un desbordamiento de pila por el limite de Integer de `2 147 483 648` que serian nueve digitos.

**Actualizacion:**

Tambien puedes utilizar la clase [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) que no tiene un limite definido como `double`:

```
//..
BigInteger numeroBigInt = new BigInteger(numerosString);
BigInteger resultado = numeroBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(k)));
```

Comment: Buena acotación, podría ser `BigInteger big = new BigInteger("12345"); big.multiply(k);` para evitar esa situación :P

Comment: Cierto, cierto.

Comment: que libreria se necesita para tener el BigInteger? @ArieCwHat

Comment: @Michelle Es nativa, solo tienes que importar la clase `java.math.BigInteger;`

Comment: Es recomendado utilizar StringBuilder al realizar concatenaciones, mas aun en un loop para no instanciar objetos innecesarios. Aqui esta bien explicado: http://www.pellegrino.link/2015/08/22/string-concatenation-with-java-8.html

Comment: Sale un error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, no ocupe el bigInteger ocupe el double.

Comment: Cuantos elementos estas agregando a la lista?

Comment: 1 o 2, pero tu codigo es solo una parte de todo un codigo que tengo, en si, el codigo completo tiene que calcular una division entre 2 numeros

Comment: Bueno en ese caso sería un poco difícil responder.

Answer (score 3):

Para concatenar todos los elementos puedes recorrer la lista y utilizar el metodo `.append(Int n)` de [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Al finalizar el recorrido el StringBuilder tendrá como valor la concatenación de los dígitos de los números y puedes crear un Integer mediante `Integer.valueOf(String string)`

La operación `valueOf` no es segura, puede arrojar [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) para strings como "12a1" o "12-12", por lo que si tuvieras valores negativos obtendrías dicha excepción.

A su vez como comenta **@Arie CwHat** en la respuesta de **@Einer**, crear un `Integer` a partir de una cantidad de dígitos variable y potencialmente superior a la precisión máxima no es una buena idea.

Para evitar este problema podemos utilizar `BigInteger`, el cual no tiene una precisión máxima definida sino que esta puede crecer desde `-2^Integer.MAX_VALUE` (exclusivo) hasta `2^Integer.MAX_VALUE` (inclusivo), donde `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^32 - 1` (Extraido de [Is there a upper bound to biginteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693273/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-biginteger))

```
   public static BigInteger listMultiplication(List<Integer> list, int k){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer num : list) {
            builder.append(num);
        }
        try{
            System.out.println("Multiplicando "+builder.toString()+ " por "+k);
            BigInteger concatNumber= new BigInteger(builder.toString()); 
            return concatNumber.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(k)); 

        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Formato numérico invalido: "+builder.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(2, 8, 9, 1, 4, 0, 6);
System.out.println(listMultiplication(numbers, 1));
System.out.println(listMultiplication(numbers, 2));
System.out.println(listMultiplication(numbers, 10));
```

> Multiplicando 2891406 por 1 2891406
>
> Multiplicando 2891406 por 2 5782812
>
> Multiplicando 2891406 por 10 28914060

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo de como podrias hacerlo: (pero hay muchas otras formas)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        lista.add(1);
        lista.add(2);
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(4);
        lista.add(2);

        int potencia = 0, suma = 0, k = 2;
        for (int i = lista.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--, potencia++) {
            // esto es igual a lista[lista.largo - indice] * 10^indice, 
            // pero separo potencia e indice para que quede claro
            // suma += lista.get(i) * Math.pow(10, lista.size() - i);

            suma += lista.get(i) * Math.pow(10, potencia);
        }

        // antes de este print el resultado es 
        // suma = (1 * 10^4) + (2 * 10^3) + (3 * 10^2) + (4 * 10^1) + (5 * 10^0)
        System.out.println(suma * k);
    }
}
```